# Use value of DOM element

Tags: dart

Before of the latest update, i wrote this code for example

```html
<input type="text" id="link">
<p> {{variable}} </p>
```

```dart
// other code
var input = query('#link');
var variable = input.value;
```

This snippet of code still work, but anyone know why the editor reports this message?

```
"value" in not a member of Element
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dart Editor reports that, because it thinks `input` variable is an instance of `Element`. Why? Because `query()` always returns an element, but the editor can't know that *in your case*, it's an input (of type `InputElement`).

You can ignore the warning. The IDE just can't know that the queried result is an `InputElement`, unless you tell it:

```dart
InputElement input = query('#link');
```

or I think this also works:

```dart
var input = query('input#link');
```

If you really want to tell the Dart runtime that you expect a variable to be of a certain type, you can use the cast operator: `as`. This has the advantage of informing the editor of the expected type, and it will also throw an error if the variable is not of the expected type.

```dart
var input = query('#link') as InputElement;
```

Note that Dart is a dynamic language, so I caution against using `as` unless you think other developers might be confused about your intent.